# entrecruzar categorías en wordpress / elementor

Tags: wordpress, elementor

estoy modificando el sitio web de una universidad, y he creado un Custom Post Type para cargar todas las carreras de la universidad.

El problema está cuando quiero mostrar los post mediante Elementor, puedo elegir cada categoría correspondiente por ejemplo:

- carrera de grado
- modalidad a distancia

Pero esto me traería todos los post con dichas categorías, y mostrar los post que cumplan con ambas categorías.

Que alternativas tengo para resolverlo, ya intentamos idear un arbol de categoías, pero sería inmenso y problemático, y la verdad que si hay alguna manera de cruzar las categorías a la hora de mostrar los posteos, el problema estaría solucionado.

Muchas gracias

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a [ES.so] Puedes explicarte mejor, no logro entender exactamente que quieres lograr, también seria bueno que pongas el código que haz intentado, por favor lee [ask]